# How to bind a color to a card in MaterializeCSS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, vuex, materialize

I am attempting to build a *Vue.js* interface that returns colored *MaterializeCSS* cards to the screen. `post.color` (stored as a hex code in a separate database) is one of several items looped through in a `v-for` loop, as seen below:

```
      <div
        v-for="post in posts"
        :key="post._id"
      >
        <div class="card darken-1" :color="post.color">
          <div class="card-content left-align">
            <span class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</span>
            <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am attempting to bind `post.color` to the card, in order to style the card with that respective color. I tried adding `:color="post.color"` to the outermost card element, but this did not work. What is the proper way to bind a looped-through color property to a *MaterializeCSS* card? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` is an HTML native element which have a fixed number of attributes, it's not a Vue component which accept some defined props, so, in order to achieve your goal you should use style attribute and add the following rule :

```
 <div class="card darken-1" :style="{background:post.color+'!important'}">
```